# Installing Jmemorize (flashcard) on Ubuntu

Tags: java, javascript

I want to install jmemorize (flashcard app) that I downloaded from sourceforge (link below) on ubuntu. It might be very simple that the developer didn't bother himself to explain but I'm stuck in it and have no clue.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmemorize/

To all future readers of this questions: Corona-virus has taken over the world these days.

Comment: Look again: On that Sourceforge page is a link to the newer Github page, which includes instructions on how to run the software. The instructions assume that you already have Jave installed. Note that it's very old (8 years!), and may not work anymore with current versions of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-javase5-downloads.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR) `jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin`
2. `cd ~/Downloads && chmod +x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin`
3. Run it by `./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin`, press and hold <kbd>Enter</kbd> and at the end of license agreement input `yes` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   Folder `jdk1.5.0_22/` will be created in your current directory.
4. Being in your current directory, you could launch your app.

   ```
   jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java -jar jMemorize-1.3.0.jar
   ```

The file and folder are in my `~/Downloads` directory:

```
/home/user/Downloads/jdk1.5.0_22/
/home/user/Downloads/jMemorize-1.3.0.jar
```

To make it executable from applications launcher do the next:

- `cd ~/ && mkdir .local/share/jmemorize`
- `mv Downloads/jMemorize-1.3.0.jar .local/share/jmemorize/`
- `mv Downloads/jdk1.5.0_22 .local/share/jmemorize/`
- `gedit .local/share/applications/jmemorize.desktop` and past the next text in to it:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=jmemorize
  Comment=Jmemorize flashcard app
  Exec=/home/your_user_name/.local/share/jmemorize/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java -jar /home/your_user_name/.local/share/jmemorize/jMemorize-1.3.0.jar
  Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=Education
  ```

  Change `your_user_name` in `Exec` to your actual username. Save it and exit gedit.
- `chmod +x .local/share/applications/jmemorize.desktop`

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you @Gryu it solved the problem